# Focus trap with vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vueuse

I'm using usefocustrap from vue use in my App.vue but I am unable to make the component work with elements within a ShadowDOM slot. Is there a way to have a single focus trap contain elements from both the ShadowDOM and elements passed in via the slot? or any other library?

basicDialog.vue

```
<div ref="target">
        <!-- @slot Use this slot for primary action -->
        <slot name="primary-action"></slot>
   </div>
```

const { hasFocus, activate, deactivate } = useFocusTrap(target, {
immediate: true,
})

App.vue

```
  <basic-dialog v-if="show">
    <!-- this is my custom button, which already have a tabindex=0-->
    <my-custom-button-vue-web-component slot="primary-action">
      <div @click="show = false">Cancel</div>
    </my-custom-button-vue-web-component>
  </basic-dialog>
```